# SSL in Heroku with a custom domain

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssl, heroku, dns

I'm using [PointHQ](http://pointhq.com) as a DNS and hosting my domain on Heroku. On default, it looks like Heroku supports https (eg. https://yodel-site.herokuapp.com), but not when you go to my site with https://yodel.co - although it works with just http://.

What do I need to do in order for SSL (https) to work on my custom domain in Heroku? Is it something to configure in my DNS ([PointHQ](http://pointhq.com)), or do I need to pay heroku for the [addon](https://elements.heroku.com/addons/ssl)?

Here's what my Heroku custom domains section looks like:
[image]

Comment: ssl endpoint you need to follow this https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ssl-endpoint

Comment: cname yodel-site.herokussl.com

Answer (score 3):

The simplest and cheapest way is to upgrade from Free to Hobby Dynos, it will cost a maximum of 7$/month for a small app, and actually probably much less because the price is prorated to the time your Dyno will run per month.(https://www.heroku.com/pricing)
This is much cheaper than the 20$/month to get the SSL Heroku add-on.

Once you have upgraded your plan from Free to Hobby, things are pretty straightforward:

- Go to your app on Heroku, go to settings, scroll down to domains and certificates, and add your domain: www.yourdomain.com
- This will automatically give you a DNS target as such www.yourdomain.com.herokudns.com
- In your Domain Host:

  - Add a CNAME record  using this DNS target, for instance on Godaddy as such: Type: CNAME   Name: www.  Value: www.yourdomain.com.herokudns.com
  - Add a redirect action from your root domain (yourdomain.com) to www.yourdomain.com

Allow a few hours for the DNS changes to propagate, and you're all set!

Comment: What does the redirect look like? CNAME?

Comment: @KevinToet It's a service provided by your Domain host, not a CNAME.  For instance on Godaddy you click on DNS settings for your domain, it will open a page in which you have a redirection section. In Directadmin it is in the advanced settings of your domain, so it really depends on you Domain host but it's basically an out-of-the-box option.

Comment: So I have already add my domain and target dsn on godaddy. After I switch to hobby dyno. What do I do next to make my custom domain ssl cert with https

Comment: It says its secure on chrome browser but not others like brave or safari. How do I make it secure on all browsers

Answer (score 1):

You will have to pay Heroku for the add-on, acquire an SSL cert, and install it [according to their instructions](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ssl-endpoint).  Note also that you should probably [avoid installing SSL at the apex](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/apex-domains), and redirect any apex traffic to the subdomain you do choose (e.g. www).

[Using CloudFlare](https://ryanboland.com/blog/completely-free-easy-to-setup-ssl/) is a reasonable approach to avoid paying Heroku's charges, though the certificate that's presented will not be your own.  You can make the choice about whether it's worth the money.